# Configuring OpenDNS system-wide on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, opendns

I am trying to use OpendNS on my Ubuntu laptop. Each time I connect to a new Wi-Fi I am forced to setup DNS on that connection. Is there a way to make the system use OpenDNS servers for any network connection I use on that laptop.

Comment: Are you connecting to each network using DHCP?

Comment: At home, I use Comcast. At work, I can hook up to Guest DNS for my personal laptop. When I am mobile, I can hook to Barnes and Nobles, Starbucks or available Wi-Fi hotspot. Whatever wi-fi I am connected, I want all the connections to have the DNS settings routed through OpenDNS servers. Is this possible?